# No analog Audio after new install

Tags: audio

A friend of mine have a small PC. As a test, i have tried to install Elementary OS on it.
Only the S/PDIF audio was shown in system, but on this PC there is are also an analog audio card.

How can I use this card for audio output? I think it should first be installed, but how? During install it did not show up.

Answer (score 1):

German:

Wenn der PC einen Intel-Chip für das Audio verwendet, verweisen wir auf diese Anleitung: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS

English:

If the PC uses an Intel chip for it's audio refer to these instructions: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS